# Cannot connect Linux to Beaglebone Network Peer to Peer

Tags: linux, networking

I'd really appreciate some help getting a peer to peer network between Ubuntu 20.04 and a Beaglebone black

I'm using networkd on Ubuntu and have fixed the ip to 10.0.0.97/24 in netplan config files

On the BBB its set via the /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0 config file

I'll tell you what works first

Any windows machine to the BBB works (proves the BBB is happy).

Ubuntu to BBB works via a switch.

Ubuntu to Windows works using a switch or straight cable

But I cant connect Ubuntu to BBB via a cable (straight or crossover) and have the link come up in any way.  By this I mean 'ip a' shows NO-CARRIER as if the cable isnt actually plugged in and 'ethtool eno2' show link connected as false

My netplan config file is really simple

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
     eno1:
       dhcp4: true
       optional: true
     eno2:
       addresses:
         - 10.0.0.97/24
```

eno1 is connected to our corp network and we are given an ip address successfully

Any tips as to what is wrong connecting directly to a effectively another Linux machine?

ta

J

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it and hope this may help someone else.  The Linux machine did not support 100mb link (only 1 & 10gb).  The BBB only supported upto 100mb.  The reason why switches and Windows laptops made things work is they supported both.